# How to read unicode from oracle database c++

Tags: c++, windows, oracle, occi

I am trying to select string written in Arabic letters from oracle database using C++
The problem is i read Chinese characters instead
I am using their [globalization guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/globalization.htm#LNCPP20416)

```
Environment* env = Environment::createEnvironment(" US7ASCII","OCCIUTF16");
Connection* con=env->createConnection("","","");
Statement* stmt= con->createStatement("select name from table where id=10");
ResultSet* rs= stmt->executeQuery();
While(rs->next())
{
   rs->getUString(1);
}
```

So how can i read it accurately  or what i am missing

Comment: Please post output of `select parameter, value from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%SET%';` and what is the exact data type of `name` column ?

Comment: What is client OS where C++ code runs ? It is Windows with GUI  or in character mode ? is this Linux with GUI or character mode ?

Comment: Name is varchar 2, nls_nchar_characterset AL16UTF16. NLS_CHARACTERSET. AR8MSWIN1256. It runs on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code modification:

```
Environment* env = Environment::createEnvironment("AR8MSWIN1256","OCCIUTF16");
```

Comment: What is your regional Windows environment ? Do you run the code in GUI or character mode ? What is the output of `chcp` run in `cmd.exe` ?

Comment: I am debugging the code in the back end ATM if this is what you mean. I have the GUI using winapi ready and it display data accurately, so it's not a gui problem.  chcp shows active code page720

Comment: What we need to know if Windows runs with  Arabic settings, Chinese settings, America settings, etc. ? What is the language used by Windows to display text, menu options, dialog boxes, etc. ? What we currently know is that code page 720 is Arabic.

Comment: Oh its English UK

Comment: Maybe you need some Windows setup to have arabic characters in GUI. But I cannot help on Windows side.